# Selenium 2/Webdriver + python + jenkins. How can I generate xml output for hudson for test reports?

Tags: python, jenkins, selenium-webdriver

I have python unittest tests using Selenium 2 and I can run it fine on my computer but now I want to use it with Jenkins. In the "execute shell", I call my script that runs all my Selenium tests but even though I get an Error or Fail for the tests, Jenkins says "Finished: SUCCESS" in the console output and thinks it passed in the console output.

1) Why does it think it passed? How can I let Jenkins detect it actually failed?

2) How can I generate an XML report of the test results so that it is compatible with JUnit and Jenkins? (testrunner?)

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show the command your running in Jenkins?

Comment: @lazy1 It's just `python2.7 start-tests.py`. Inside that I have suite definitions, then `if __name__=='__main__'`, ......then `unittest.TextTestRunner().run(suite())`.

Comment: Hard to tell. My *guess* will be that failure in the test does not result in non-zero value returned from the script. Maybe another command after the `python start-tests.py` that does not fail?

Answer (score 2):

For 2 you can use [nosetests --with-xunit](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).